# In ReactJS, how to set one select dropdown based on another, both ajax?

Tags: reactjs

**Specific to initial page load**:

In my ReactJS page I have two dropdowns/select elements.  The first is loaded via Ajax, and the second is loaded via Ajax.  The values in the second select depend on which value is selected in the first select.

This is straightforward to do in response to the user changing the first select because an onchange event is fired and I can then update the second dropdown.

But I cannot work out how to do the initial page load.  During initial page load, a value will be set in the first dropdown, but I can't work out how to get that value so I can load the values for the second dropdown.

Comment: Share your code and people will help.

Comment: @BurreIfort thanks for chiming in but I worked it out 2 and a half years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Just fire the request in `componentDidMount()`. This will give you an opportunity to update the second select.

Answer (score 0):

Use state to store the first dropdown value.

```js
render() {
let secondDrop = null;
if (this.state.firstDropValue) {
  secondDrop = (
    <div id='secondDrop'>...
    )
else secondDrop = null;
return (
  <div id='firstDrop'>...</div>
  {secondDrop}
 )
}
```